# MongoDB text search does not work correctly on some words

Tags: mongodb, search, text

I have created a text index on my items collection as follows:

```
db.items.createIndex({"$**":"text"})
```

Doing this search:

```
db.items.find({ "PId" : null, $text : { $search : "Youu" } })
```

returns this document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59e7494fd28008300c727c73"),
    "_t": "MongoItem",
    "Props": {
        "Identification\Display Name": "Test",
        "Rainfall\Customer Identification\ Internal ": false,
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Financial Start Date ": NumberLong("77760000000000 "),
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Error Alarm Threshold ": NumberLong(12),
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Calculation Start Time ": NumberLong("636188256000000000 "),
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Time Zone ": 1,
        "Identification\ Description ": "Youu "
    },
    "FId ": BinData(3, "a9Bg/nK2W0W90AKosCJvRw=="),
    "PId": null,
    "FName": "map sewer test",
    "DatUpV": NumberLong(0),
    "DatChV": NumberLong(0),
    "DatUpChV": NumberLong(0),
    "ChItV": NumberLong(0),
    "PropV": NumberLong("636487544940502958")
}
```

which is what I would expect.

However, if I change the Identification\Description property to "You" and do this search:

```
db.items.find({ "PId" : null, $text : { $search : "You" } })
```

I do not get any results! The property has definitely been set to "You" as I have carried out the search without the text part and checked the entry.

I am totally confused why this is not working. Any ideas?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: OK - you is a stop word!!! This is why it is not working

Comment: Thank you for this! I couldn't use text search with the word "what" and i could not understand why. When setting the defualt_language: 'none' on the index it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you read through the documentation but here it is just to make sure.

[$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)
It will search all your fields for the specified text. But it has to match completely.

With your search `db.items.find({ "PId" : null, $text : { $search : "You" } })` you would only find a document that also had a field who's value was *You*. E.g.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59e7494fd28008300c727c73"),
    "_t": "MongoItem",
    "Props": {
        "Identification\Display Name": "Test",
        "Rainfall\Customer Identification\ Internal ": false,
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Financial Start Date ": NumberLong("77760000000000 "),
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Error Alarm Threshold ": NumberLong(12),
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Calculation Start Time ": NumberLong("636188256000000000 "),
        "Rainfall\ Customer\ Time Zone ": 1,
        "Identification\ Description ": "You "
    },
    "FId ": BinData(3, "a9Bg/nK2W0W90AKosCJvRw=="),
    "PId": null,
    "FName": "map sewer test",
    "DatUpV": NumberLong(0),
    "DatChV": NumberLong(0),
    "DatUpChV": NumberLong(0),
    "ChItV": NumberLong(0),
    "PropV": NumberLong("636487544940502958")
}
```

What you are searching for is rather [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). With `$regex` on the other hand you'd have to search for a specific field.
If you'd want to search a particular field in this case

**"Props.Identification\ Description "**

then you could search like this:

```
{ "Props.Identification\\ Description ": {$regex: /you/, $options: 'i'} }
```

the options are not necessary but you can add them if you want specific options, like in this case `$options: 'i'` would make it case insensitive. 
Otherwise you could search like that:

```
{ "Props.Identification\\ Description ": {$regex: /You/} }
```